# Normalize components in a language model

Tags: model, machine-learning, normalization, normalize

I have the following language model

A = X + Y + Z

X, Y and Z have different value ranges.

I need to normalize each of these components individually. However, I can't know the min and max of each range until I compute all values.

How can I normalize these components in single run?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a single run? Finding max and min values takes only one additional run that doesn't change time complexity. Also note that this question doesn't concern language modeling, and even equation is redundant - the question is about normalization without knowing min and max values.

Comment: I'm actually doing a sentiment classification in streaming fashion, so I need to do normalization based on the arriving data. In this case I don't know the min and max.

Comment: What classifier are you using? What actually are `x`, `Y` and `Z`? Most probably you either do not need normalize your data or can do it by simply keeping track of only current min and max.